# Can't load data with attributes from other page into div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i click on

> .btnavi a

nothing happens using this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#baby" ).load( "getbaby.php",function(){
    $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element
    }); //load initial records
    $(".btnavi a").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show(); //hide loading element
        var day = $(this).attr('name'); //get page number from name attr
        $("#baby").load("getbaby.php/"+day,function(){
        $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element
        });
    });
});
```

Page is loaded normally when i open first time, when i click .btnavi a, there is no new load. getbaby.php accepts /0-9 values so getbaby.php/0 works, returns echo tables and some contents what i want to load dinamicly...

Variable **day** has value as i want (0-6) when i alert, so click functions works, problem is in this part:

```
$("#baby").load("getbaby.php/"+day,function(){
            $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element
            });
```

probably...

**UPDATE**

getbaby.php code:

```
<?PHP
include_once("php/class.connect.php");
include_once("php/functions.php");
include_once("php/config.php");
//include("php/header_days.php");
include_once("php/class.provider.php");

header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
/*ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);*/
// ------- GETTING THE STRINGS FROM URL

$conn = new Connect();
$PDO = $conn->PDO;

$x = $_GET['day']; 
$sport = $_GET['sport']; 
$league = $_GET['league'];
$lgid = decode36($_GET['lgid']);
$pro = new Provider();
/*if(empty($x)){
$x = 'all';
}*/

if(isset($_GET['day'])){
    echo "<script>alert({$_GET['day']})</script>";
}

if($x=='' && $league !='') $x='all';
else if($x='') $x=0;
// ---------------------- QUERY WILL DISPLAY ALL EVENTS ON THE DAY
if (($league == '') && ($sport == '') && ($x != 'all')) {
    $where = "WHERE TO_DAYS(baby.DateTime) = (TO_DAYS(NOW())+'$x') AND TIMEDIFF(baby.DateTime,now()) > 0"; }
    //$where = "WHERE TIMEDIFF(fixtures.matchdate,now())  > 0"; }
// ----------------------- QUERY WILL DISPLAY A SPECIFIC SPORT ON THE DAY
elseif (($league == '') && ($sport != '') && ($x != 'all')) {
    $where = "WHERE TO_DAYS(baby.DateTime) = (TO_DAYS(NOW())+'$x') AND TIMEDIFF(baby.DateTime,now()) > 0 AND info.sportid = '$sport'"; }
// -------------------- QUERY WILL DISPLAY A SPECIFIC LEAGUE
elseif (($lgid != '') && ($x != 'all')) {
    //$x = $pro->getDay();
    $where = "WHERE TO_DAYS(baby.DateTime) = (TO_DAYS(NOW())+'$x') AND TIMEDIFF(baby.DateTime,now()) > 0 AND baby.LeagueID = '$lgid'"; }
// ----------------- QUERY WILL DISPLAY ALL MATCHES IN A SINGLE LEAGUE REGARDLESS OF THE DAY
elseif ($x == 'all') {
    $where = "WHERE baby.LeagueID = '$lgid' AND TIMEDIFF(baby.DateTime,now()) > 0"; }

//**************************  Q U E R Y   S T A R T  *************
    $SQL = "SELECT
    baby.DateTime AS eventstartdate, baby.FixtureID AS eventid,
    baby.HomeTeam AS localname, baby.AwayTeam AS visitorname,
    baby.EventName AS eventname, baby.SportID AS sportid,
    baby.SportName AS sportname, baby.Country AS countryname,
    baby.League AS league, baby.TopOddsHome AS oddsHome, 
    baby.TopOddsDraw AS oddsDraw,baby.TopOddsAway AS oddsAway, 
    baby.Justicia AS justicia, baby.LeagueID AS tournament_stageid
    FROM
    baby
    {$where} 
    ORDER BY sportid ASC, countryname ASC, league ASC, eventstartdate ASC, eventid ASC";
//*********************************  Q U E R Y   E N D  ***************

$result = $PDO->query($SQL);

if($result === FALSE) { die($PDO->errorInfo());  }

echo "<table style='font-size:11px; background-color: #c8ccce; width:100%;'>";

$sport1 = '';$template1 = '';$stage1 = ''; $leaguecounter='0';
$table20 = 'images/black20bg5.png';     //STARI PNG S LIJEPIM TAMNOPLAVIM GRADIJENTOM, poveæan na 24px

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($db_field=$result->fetch()){
//********** START TITLES ***********
$matchtitle = htmlstring($db_field['eventname']) . " odds comparison. Click to see all odds.";
//$matchtitle = "Best betting odds comparison on " . htmlstring($db_field['eventname']) . ". Click to see all odds.";

// --- Displaying Header only if the value it doesn't match previous value
if ($db_field['league'] != $template1) {
// --- Assigning the league URL which displays all the available matches from that League   
$sport = $db_field['sportid'];$league = $_GET['league'];$x = "all";
//$tourname = htmlstring($db_field['tournament_templatename']) . " " . htmlstring($db_field['tournament_stagename']);
$tourid = $db_field['tournament_stageid'];
$country = $db_field['countryname'];
$country = str_replace(" ", "-", $country);
if ( $country == "International" ) { $country = ""; } else { $country = $country. "-"; }
$stage = utf8_encode($db_field['league']);
//ako nije nogomet, onda dodajemo ime sporta ispred svega, a za tenis dodajemo i tempname (ATP, WTA, challenger)
    if ( $db_field['sportid'] != '1' && $db_field['sportid'] != '2' ) {
    $country = str_replace(" ", "-", $db_field['sportname']) . "-" . $country;
    }
    if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '2' ) {
    //maknuo ovo u pokušaju da riješim da se teniski parovi uopæe prikazuju, ali vjerojatno ovo nije bio razlog
    //$country = str_replace(" ", "-", $db_field['sportname']) . "-" . $db_field['tournament_templatename'] . "-" . $country;
    $country = str_replace(" ", "-", $db_field['sportname']) . "-" . $country;
    }
$country = str_replace("&", "and", $country);
$leagueurl = "/league/" . toAscii($stage) . "-odds" . "/" . code36($tourid) . "/";
$leaguetitle = "Best betting odds comparison, schedules and dates for " . html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['countryname'])) . " " .html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['league'])) . " " . $db_field['sportname'] . " league. Click to see all matches and the season schedule!";
//************ END TITLES ***********


// --- Assigning the image URLs for Inverted Sports Icons and Flags
$imgurl = "images/" . $db_field['sportname'] . " Odds Comparison Inverted.png";     $imgalt = $db_field['sportname'] . " Odds Comparison";
$countryurl = "images/flags/" . $db_field['countryname'] . ".png";  $countryalt = $db_field['countryname'];

// --- Setting the colspan value
if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '2' || $db_field['sportid'] == '26' || $db_field['sportid'] == '33' || $db_field['sportid'] == '51' || $db_field['sportid'] == '73' || $db_field['sportid'] == '24' || $db_field['sportid'] == '74' || $db_field['sportid'] == '75' ) { $colspan = '4'; }
elseif ( $db_field['sportid'] == '23' && $db_field['countryname'] == 'USA' ) { $colspan = '4'; }
elseif ( $db_field['sportid'] == '23' && $db_field['countryname'] != 'USA' ) { $colspan = '3'; }
else $colspan = '3';

$shortcountry = str_replace(" ", "", $db_field['countryname']);
$flag = "flag" . $shortcountry;
$icon = "usualsport" . $db_field['sportid'];
$icon_i ="usualsport". $db_field['sportid'] . "i";
$sportalt = $db_field['sportname'] . " Odds Comparison";

// --- Displaying the Inverted Sport Icon, Flag and the League name
$temp_name = strtoupper(html_entity_decode($db_field['countryname']));
if ( $db_field['countryname'] == "International" ) { $temp_name = ""; }
$stage_name = strtoupper(html_entity_decode(utf8_encode(mb_strtoupper($db_field['league']))));

//stavljamo razmake izmeðu raznih liga, ali ne za prvu ligu na popisu tako da bude odmah uz gornji menu s datumima
if ($leaguecounter=='1') { echo "<tr style='height:10px; background-color: #fff;'>" , "<td colspan='7'>" , "</td>" , "</tr>";}
$leaguecounter='1';

$sportt = $db_field['sportname'];
if ($sportt=="soccer") { $sportt="Football";}

//echo "<tr style='height:23px; background-color: #e1e1e1;'>" , "<td colspan='$colspan'>" , "<span style='color: #000;'>" , "<matches-url>" , "<a href='$leagueurl' title='$leaguetitle''>" , strtoupper($db_field['sportname']) , " " , "<img src='$countryurl' alt='$countryalt' width='16' height='11' style='margin-left:4px; margin-right:4px; margin-bottom:0px; border-style: none;'/>" , " " , $temp_name , " " , $stage_name , "</span>" , "</a>" , "</matches-url>" , "</td>";
echo "<tr style='height:23px; background-color: #e1e1e1;'>" , "<td colspan='$colspan'>" , "<span style='color: #000;'>" , "<matches-url>" , "<a href='$leagueurl' title='$leaguetitle''>" , strtoupper($sportt) , " " , "<img src='$countryurl' alt='$countryalt' width='16' height='11' style='margin-left:4px; margin-right:4px; margin-bottom:0px; border-style: none;'/>" , " " , $stage_name, "</span>" , "</a>" , "</matches-url>" , "</td>";


//CSS SPRITES CODE, SAME AS ABOVE BUT WITH SPRITES
//echo "<tr style='height:23px; background-color: #e1e1e1;'>" , "<td colspan='$colspan'>" , "<a href='$leagueurl' title='$leaguetitle''>" , "<span style='color: #000;'>" , "<matches-url>" , strtoupper($db_field['sportname']) , " " , "<img src='transparent.gif' class='flags' id='$flag' alt='$countryalt' width='16' height='12' style='margin-left:4px; margin-right:4px; margin-bottom:-1px; border-style: none;'/>" , " " , $temp_name , " " , $stage_name , "</matches-url>" , "</span>" , "</a>" , "</td>";

/*
echo "<tr class='20' border='0' style='background-image: url($table20); background-color: black; color: white; border-color: #444;  border-bottom:0px; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:0px solid black;'>" , "<td colspan='$colspan' style='border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>" , "<a href='$leagueurl' title='$leaguetitle' style='text-decoration:none;'>" , "<span style='color: #fff; text-decoration:none;'>" , "<matches-url>" , strtoupper($db_field['sportname']) , " " , "<img src='transparent.gif' class='flags' id='$flag' alt='$countryalt' width='16' height='12' style='margin-left:4px; margin-right:4px; margin-bottom:-1px; border-style: none;'/>" , " " , $temp_name , " " , $stage_name , "</matches-url>" , "</span>" , "</a>" , "</td>";
*/

    // 1X2 SPORTS (Soccer, Ice Hockey, Handball, Bandy, Floorball, Rugby)
    if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '1' || $db_field['sportid'] == '5' || $db_field['sportid'] == '20' || $db_field['sportid'] == '25' || $db_field['sportid'] == '28' || $db_field['sportid'] == '29' ) {
        echo "<td style='width:42px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "1" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:42px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "X" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:42px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "2" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:74px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "SURE BET" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   

    // 12 SPORTS (Tennis)
    if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '2' ) {
        echo "<td style='width:42px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "1" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:42px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "2" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:74px; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom:0;'>", "<matches-header>" , "SURE BET" , "</matches-header>" , "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   




} // ZAVRŠAVA DIO SA ZAGLAVLJEM LIGE

// Setting the current league variables to see if it the next match is from the same league or the new league (needing to display a header)
$sport1 = $db_field['sportname']; $template1 = $db_field['league'];

    //2012-01-06 16:45:00
    $sub_month = substr($db_field['eventstartdate'], -14, 2); $sub_day = substr($db_field['eventstartdate'], -11, 2);
    $sub_hour = substr($db_field['eventstartdate'], -8, 2); $sub_minute = substr($db_field['eventstartdate'], -5, 2);
    $subdate = $sub_day . "." . $sub_month . ". "; $subtime = $sub_hour . ":" . $sub_minute;

    $string1 = ""; //http://www.oddsnavigator.com or current page
    $string6 = "?type=" . $db_field['type']; // bet type
    $string7 = "&scope=" . "ord"; // bet scope
    $string8 = "&display=1"; // calls solo-match
    $string9 = "&day=" . $x; // needed for the left menu to stay accurate
    $string10 = "&sport=" . $db_field['sportid']; // needed to call the proper solo-X bet type and scope
    $string11 = "&sort=" . "juice_a"; // sorting options for solo-X
    $string12 = "&matchid=" . $db_field['eventid']; // match ID, will stay on rewritten version to prevent duplicate tournament stage URLS

    $url = $string1 . "match/" . $db_field['sportname'] . "/" . $db_field['tournament_templatename'] . " " . $db_field['tournament_stagename'] . "/" . str_replace("/", " ", htmlstring($db_field['eventname'])) . "/" . $db_field['type'] . "-" . "ord" . "-" . "juice_a" . "-" . $db_field['eventid'] . "-" . $x . "-" . $db_field['sportid'] . "-" . "1";

        $oddsHome = number_format($db_field['oddsHome'], 3, '.', '');   // 3 decimals
        $oddsDraw = number_format($db_field['oddsDraw'], 3, '.', '');   // 3 decimals
        $oddsAway = number_format($db_field['oddsAway'], 3, '.', '');   // 3 decimals

        if ($oddsHome == '0') { $oddsHome = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>"; }
        if ($oddsDraw == '0') { $oddsDraw = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>"; }
        if ($oddsAway == '0') { $oddsAway = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>"; }

        $justicia = (float) $justicia;
        $justicia = number_format($db_field['justicia'], 2, '.', '');

        if ($justicia > 0 ) { // RAÈUNANJE ULOGA ZA SIGURNU OKLADU
            $multiplier = 100 / $justicia;
            $justiciabackup = $justicia;
            $justicia = "<span style='color:#008aff'>" . "YES +" . $justicia . "%" . "</span>"; 
            $one = 1 / $oddsHome;
            $zero = $oddsDraw == 0? 0 : 1 / $oddsDraw;
            $two = 1 / $oddsAway;
            $one = $multiplier * $one * 100;
            $zero = $multiplier * $zero * 100;
            $two = $multiplier * $two * 100;
            $one = number_format($one, 1, '.', ''); // 1 decimal spot
            $zero = number_format($zero, 1, '.', '');   // 1 decimal spot
            $two = number_format($two, 1, '.', ''); // 1 decimal spot
        }
        if ($justicia == '0.00') { $justicia = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "no (0.00%)" . "</span>"; }
        if (($justicia < 0 ) && ($justicia > -50)) { $justicia = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "no (" . $justicia . "%)" . "</span>"; }
        if ($justicia < -50 ) { // it happens when Betfair lists starting odds, always 1.020 1.250 1.020, justicia -176.08%
            $justicia = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "-" . "</span>";
            $oddsHome = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>";
            $oddsDraw = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>";
            $oddsAway = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>";
        }
        if ($oddsHome == "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {$justicia = "<span style='color:#888'>" . "-" . "</span>"; }


    if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '1' || $db_field['sportid'] == '5' || $db_field['sportid'] == '20' || $db_field['sportid'] == '25' || $db_field['sportid'] == '29' || $db_field['sportid'] == '28' ) { // 1x2 sports: soccer, ice hockey, handball, basketball, bandy, floorball
        $string6 = "?type=" . "1x2";

        // EVERYTHING BELOW MUST MATCH TER_MATCHES.PHP AND OTHER INSTANCES OF CREATING URLS
        $local = toAscii(utf8_encode($db_field['localname']));
        $visitor = toAscii(utf8_encode($db_field['visitorname']));

        //echo $local . $visitor . '<br>';

        $eventy = $local . "-v-" . $visitor;

        $country = htmlstring($db_field['countryname']);
        $country = str_replace(" ", "-", $country);
        $country = str_replace("&", "and", $country);

        $stagey = toAscii(utf8_encode($db_field['league']));    
        //$stagey = str_replace(" ", "-", htmlstring($db_field['league']));     
/*
        $stagey = str_replace("/", "-", $stagey);
        $stagey = str_replace(":", "", $stagey);
        $eventy = str_replace("/", "-", $eventy);   
        // EVERYTHING ABOVE MUST MATCH TER_MATCHES.PHP AND OTHER INSTANCES OF CREATING URLS
    */  
        $sportlink = "1x2-ord-juice_a";

        $url = $eventy . "/" . $stagey . "/"  . code36($db_field['eventid']);


    //$url = $string1 . "/" . htmlstring($db_field['eventname']) . "/" . htmlstring($db_field['countryname']) . " " . htmlstring($db_field['league']) . "/" . "1x2" . "-" . "ord" . "-" . "juice_a" . "-" . $db_field['eventid'] . "-" . $x . "-" . $db_field['sportid'] . "-" . "1" . "-odds/";

        echo "<tr class='brown' style='height:20px;'>" , "<td style='width:38px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subdate , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td style='width:36px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subtime , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='".$url."' title='$matchtitle'>" ,html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['eventname'])) , "</td>";
/*
        echo "<tr class='brown'>" , "<td style='width:35px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subdate , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td style='width:33px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subtime , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$url' title='$matchtitle'>" , html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['eventname']));
*/

if ($oddsHome != "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {         
        $odds1x2 = "1";
        $popurl = $base."/php/popup-1x2.php" . "?popmatch=" . $db_field['eventid'] . "&odds1x2=" . $odds1x2;        

        //echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsHome , "</td>";

        echo "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$popurl' toptions='resizable = 0' class='tu_iframe_210x134' title='Click to see top 5 odds for this bet in a pop-up.'>" , $oddsHome , "</a>" , "</td>";       
}
else {
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;' title='No bets available for this event'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsHome , "</td>";
}       

if ($oddsDraw != "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {     
        $odds1x2 = "x";
        $popurl = "{$base}/php/popup-1x2.php" . "?popmatch=" . $db_field['eventid'] . "&odds1x2=" . $odds1x2;
//      echo "<a href='http://www.oddsnavigator.com/popup-1x2.php' class='tu_iframe_800x600'>Open Google</a>";
        echo "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$popurl' toptions='resizable = 0' class='tu_iframe_210x134' title='Click to see top 5 odds for this bet in a pop-up.'>" , $oddsDraw , "</a>" , "</td>";
}
else {
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;' title='No bets available for this event'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsDraw , "</td>";
}       
        //echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsDraw , "</td>";
if ($oddsAway != "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {
        $odds1x2 = "2";
        $popurl = $base."/php/popup-1x2.php" . "?popmatch=" . $db_field['eventid'] . "&odds1x2=" . $odds1x2;
        echo "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$popurl' toptions='resizable = 0' class='tu_iframe_210x134' title='Click to see top 5 odds for this bet in a pop-up.'>" , $oddsAway , "</a>" , "</td>";
}
else {
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;' title='No bets available for this event'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsAway , "</td>";
}       


        if ($justiciabackup > 0 ) { echo "<td title='To make a profit of 100 units regardless of the outcome, bet $one units on HOME, $zero units on DRAW and $two units on AWAY.' style='border:1px solid #444;'>"; }
        else { echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>"; }
        echo "<matches-list>", $justicia , "</matches-list>" , "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    if ( $db_field['sportid'] == '2' ) { // 12 sports: tennis
        $string6 = "?type=" . "12";
        $local = str_replace(" ", "-", $db_field['localname']);
        $visitor = str_replace(" ", "-", $db_field['visitorname']);
        $eventy = $local . "-" . $visitor;
        $eventy = rawurlencode($eventy);

        $country = $db_field['countryname'];
        $country = str_replace(" ", "-", $country);
        $country = str_replace("&", "and", $country);

        $stagey = rawurlencode($db_field['league']);    
        $stagey = str_replace(" ", "-", htmlstring($db_field['league']));       

        $stagey = str_replace("/", "-", $stagey);
        $eventy = str_replace("/", "-", $eventy);   

        $sportlink = "12-ord-juice_a";

        $url = $base . "/" . $eventy . "/" . $country . "-" . $stagey . "/" . $sportlink . "-" . $db_field['eventid'] . "-" . "1" . "-" . $db_field['sportid'] . "-" . "1" . "-odds/";


    //$url = $string1 . "/" . htmlstring($db_field['eventname']) . "/" . htmlstring($db_field['countryname']) . " " . htmlstring($db_field['league']) . "/" . "1x2" . "-" . "ord" . "-" . "juice_a" . "-" . $db_field['eventid'] . "-" . $x . "-" . $db_field['sportid'] . "-" . "1" . "-odds/";

        echo "<tr class='brown' style='height:20px;'>" , "<td style='width:35px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subdate , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td style='width:33px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subtime , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td colspan='2' class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$url' title='$matchtitle'>" , html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['eventname'])) , "</td>";
/*
        echo "<tr class='brown'>" , "<td style='width:35px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subdate , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td style='width:33px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $subtime , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$url' title='$matchtitle'>" , html_entity_decode(htmlstring($db_field['eventname']));
*/

if ($oddsHome != "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {         
        $odds1x2 = "1";
        $popurl = $base."/php/popup-1x2.php" . "?popmatch=" . $db_field['eventid'] . "&odds1x2=" . $odds1x2;        

        //echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsHome , "</td>";

        echo "<td class='btnav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$popurl' toptions='resizable = 0' class='tu_iframe_210x134' title='Click to see top 5 odds for this bet in a pop-up.'>" , $oddsHome , "</a>" , "</td>";     
}
else {
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;' title='No bets available for this event'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsHome , "</td>";
}       

        //echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsDraw , "</td>";
if ($oddsAway != "<span style='color:#888'>" . "OFF" . "</span>") {
        $odds1x2 = "2";
        $popurl = "{$base}/php/popup-1x2.php" . "?popmatch=" . $db_field['eventid'] . "&odds1x2=" . $odds1x2;
        echo "<td class='btnav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='$popurl' toptions='resizable = 0' class='tu_iframe_210x134' title='Click to see top 5 odds for this bet in a pop-up.'>" , $oddsAway , "</a>" , "</td>";
}
else {
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;' title='No bets available for this event'>" , "<matches-list>" , $oddsAway , "</td>";
}       


        if ($justiciabackup > 0 ) { echo "<td title='To make a profit of 100 units regardless of the outcome, bet $one units on HOME, $zero units on DRAW and $two units on AWAY.' style='border:1px solid #444;'>"; }
        else { echo "<td style='border:1px solid #444;'>"; }
        echo "<matches-list>", $justicia , "</matches-list>" , "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   


} // end main while db_field loop
echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
/*


if ($tourid=='200089') {
    echo  "<img src='images/australia-a-league-logo.png' alt='Australia A-League logo' height='122' width='100' align='right' >";
    echo "<h1>Australia A-League betting odds</h1> Compare Australia A-League betting odds and place your bets on the top football competition in Australia. Browse through the list of A-League matches, make your selection and place your bet. Click individual matches to see the best odds for that match, or just click the odds to see a pop-up window with the best betting odds. Stay on top of A-League odds with OddsNavigator!";
    echo "<BR/>";
    echo "<BR/>";
    echo "A-League is the top football competition in Australia and was established in 2004. Seasons run from October to May and include a 27-round regular season and a playoff tournament that culminates with the Grand Final match. The winner of the regular season tournament is dubbed 'premier' and the winner of the grand final is 'champion'. The most successful clubs are Brisbane Roar, Central Coast Mariners, Sydney FC and Melbourne Victory.";
    echo "<BR/>";
    echo "<BR/>";
    echo "Several notable world class players have played in the A-League late in their career - Robbie Fowler, Alessandro Del Piero, William Gallas, Damian Duff, Kazuyoshi Miura, Shinji Ono, Dwight Yorke, Romario and Juninho Paulista. ";
}


*/
?>
<!--POPUP-->  

<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <?PHP
    $popupmatch = $_GET['popmatch'];
    echo $popupmatch;
    include("php/popup-1x2.php");?>
</div>  
<!-- / POPUP-->
```

Comment: using developer tools in your browser, can you see that the page is being loaded?

Comment: It is loaded when page starts, when i click on navigation nothings changed. When i see under inspect element of chrome and when i click on navigation code blink red for a moment and than disappear, content is same... In getbaby.php i have this vars which is very important, can i pass data to getbaby.php using jquery? 

$x = $_GET['day']; 
$sport = $_GET['sport']; 
$league = $_GET['league'];
$lgid = decode36($_GET['lgid']);

Comment: let me rephrase that question to be a little more obvious - using developer tools, can you see if any network activity takes place at all to show that your code is at least trying to load the requested page

Comment: How element with `.btnavi a` ? Is it created by AJAX ?

Comment: to clarify ... if you browse to `http://whatever-your-domain-is.com/getbaby.php/0` you get the content you expect to be loaded into your div? It's just that URL doesn't look right for php - do you have some url rewriting happening to translate such a request to a valid one?

Comment: @JaromandaX
Yes it takes, in headers part are:

Remote Address:censured
Request URL:http://mysite/getbaby.php/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code: OK

But in Response tab content does not change

Comment: To be clear, i think now that problem is inside getbaby.php where i use:
$x = $_GET['day']; 
than i select from database where day=$x
than i echo that content, it works when i manually change /0,/1,/2,/3 but with jquery dont.

Comment: `$("#baby").load("getbaby.php",{"day": day},function(){
        $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element
        });` change load inside click as above. let's see

Comment: @jagad89 Is it code used for $_POST? 
Now with $_GET in getbaby.php not work that code..

Comment: And in network Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: @user1814358 Yes, It will use POST because we used object. What if you use `$("#baby").load("getbaby.php?day="+ day,function(){ $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element });`   Can you post your php code too? It will clear all server and client side scenario.

Comment: @jagad89 check update up..

Comment: Same is with ?day=0-9 , i have defined in .htaccess to accept /0-9

Comment: SOLVED! Here was problem else if($x='') $x=0; this works else if($x=='') $x=0; inside getbaby.php -.-

Comment: @user1814358 Very Good. Sorry My internet lost yesterday.